# Cocoa HTTP redirect?

Tags: cocoa, redirect, hosts

I know that the `/etc/hosts` file can be modified to redirect a website, but thats not really feasible from within an app. I'm wondering if there's anyway to do this from within an app and only have it redirected while that app is running.

Comment: I hope not—or at least that it would require admin powers.

Comment: Are you wanting to affect your own app or someone else's?